# Login troubles with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to log into our production site, say , "http://site.com" ,  using username "username" and password "password". When I execute the test, it reaches till the stage where the site opens, but, it doesn't enter the username and password.   The code is below:

```
package com.beginning;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.internal.runners.statements.Fail;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.junit.Assert.*;
public class testcase {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl="";
    private StringBuffer verificationerrors=new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testJUnit0() throws Exception {
        driver.get("site.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).clear();
        //System.out.println("Element found");
        driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).sendKeys("username");
        driver.findElement(By.name("j_password")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("j_password")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"submit\"]")).click();

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationerrorString=verificationerrors.toString();

        }
    private boolean isElementPresent(By by)
    {
        try {
            driver.findElement(by);
            return true;
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant HTML part of the page :

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="j_security_check">
                                        <table>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <label style="color: gray; left: 0px; top: 48px;">
                                                            Username:
                                                        </label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="text" mandatory="true" value="" name="j_username" tabindex="1">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <label style="color: gray; left: 0px; top: 96px;">
                                                            Password:
                                                        </label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="password" mandatory="true" name="j_password" value="" tabindex="2">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="2">
                                                        <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" tabindex="3" style="width: 87px;height:30px">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
```

System details :

OpenSuse 11.4,Selenium 2.8.0 ,firefox 7.

Exception raised is :

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:96)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:149)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:79)
    at com.beginning.jw.setUp(jw.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: What does the browser show? Have you tried debugging the test using Eclipse?

Comment: The browser does not start. It gets stuck at the line : driver=new FirefoxDriver() . I do a  netstat | grep 7055, but, that doesn't show any process that is listening to port 7055. So, I wonder why  it does what it does :(

Comment: What exception are you getting when the test fails?

Comment: I have added that as part of the question . Hope that helps .

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use complete name of site :

For ex:

"http://www.site.com"

use this as your url.

Comment: That was just an example .   I am infact using the exact link.   Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

In the question you mention 'it opens the site and fails to log in and in the comment you mention, 'browser does not start'. I am a bit confused :)
If I assume that the browser is not starting then it sounds like you would need to change IPv6 settings on your OpenSuse machine. Here is the link from the frequently asked questions to do so.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_WebDriver_fails_to_start_Firefox_on_Linux_due_to_java.net.

Comment: The problem when I posted the query was infact, the not logging in part. By the time, someone posted a comment,  it was  not opening. The root cause was that i was running the whole thing as root as a temporary workaround to faulty installation issues. Its fine now.  I reinstalled eclipse and other things. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

check the compatibility of mozilla with the selenium version.